# writing basic Trigger in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to use a trigger when an insert is made on a table and I can't create it because of an error.

```
   -- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Trigger (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- See additional Create Trigger templates for more
-- examples of different Trigger statements.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the function.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Nick Gowdy
-- Create date: 26/03/2013
-- Description: Insert Module ID into table based on User ID on update
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER TblAuditLogLoggingIn.ModuleID ON dbo.GenesisOnline.TblAuditLogLoggingIn.UserID
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO
```

The error is:

> Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure ModuleID, Line 6
>       The object 'TblAuditLogLoggingIn.UserID' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

The schema is dbo.GenesisOnline.TblAuditLogLoggingIn and the columns are:

- AuditID PK
- UserID
- ModuleID
- LoggedInDate

The trigger I am trying to create is for table TblAuditLogLoggingIn that I have created. But Management studio says it doesn't exist?

Comment: Does UserID exists on TblAuditLogLoggingIn?

Comment: What schema does the table belong to?

Comment: Check my updated post for answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, thanks for clarifying your question @nick gowdy. First of all SQL Server does not accept a name with a **dot (.)** on it. Then you cannot create a trigger based on a column that way, as mentioned by the previous answer. If you want to act on a column on your trigger you should do it like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TblAuditLogLoggingIn_ModuleID ON dbo.GenesisOnline
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    IF ( UPDATE(UserID) )
    BEGIN
        -- do your stuff here
    END
END
GO
```

But that would almost certainly result into `do your stuff here` gets executed all the time. If what you are trying to do is to `do your stuff` if `UserID` meet some criteria, null for example then you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @UserID int --assuming that is the type of your UserID
SELECT @UserID = UserID from inserted
IF ( @UserID is null ) -- change this to a criteria appropriate to your code
BEGIN
    -- do your stuff here
END
```